# Setup VPN on Windows 7 system

Tags: vpn

I work in an company and had servers. I am connected to the internet through netgear dgn1000 router.

We had central sql server and central project repositories on other machine.

Like Say my Machine is 192.100.0.55

Sql Server is on       192.100.0.100
Repository is on       192.100.0.200
In House Message on    192.100.0.300

Now i want to work from some other machine/home machine but still want to connect to these server to access repo, db and my resources.

The internet speed/connection is major concerned i.e It will be less bandwidth consuming and is MAX 1 Mbps.

I am thinking can VPN be ok/installed for this case and how can i setup?

I had full access to my system only and not to any other system. Can i do something that leaving my system open and this system is used as some proxy to connect to the office LAN/machines

Any help is appreciated.

If the question is not suitable for this website, let me know where i can repost it

Comment: Can i summarize your post to make it clearer: -you are working on a Win 7 PC -the PC is not located at the office you want it to connect -you want access to a server that has VPN connections enabled. If you answer these questions with yes then i have a solution and i am going to post it.

Comment: For a start, 192.168.0.300 is an invalid IP address. Octets have a maximum value of 255 - though this is normally reserved for broadcast, so the highest usable value is normally 254. Secondly, your question isn't very clear - can you clarify it as @kiltek requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have access to your system, you could setup an VPN Server ( for example OpenVPN ) on your systems at home, and connect from your office system with the vpn client.

The other direction would not work, as you need to open some ports in the office-firewall to connect to your VPN server from external networks.

Another, more simple solution, would be to use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). You could run this tool on your office PC, and work on this machine from nearly everywhere.